# Partial sums of divergent series

Tags: divergent-series

Let $\sum a_n$ be a divergent serie of positive terms.  Prove that for each positive integer $m$ there is $n>m$ such that

$$a_{m+1}+\cdots a_n> a_1+\cdots + a_{m}.$$

I tried to use that the partial sum sequence is not Cauchy but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N = a_1 + \cdots + a_m$.  Is there ever a partial sum that exceeds $2N$?

Answer (score 2):

Assume the contrary. Then the sequence $s_k=\sum_{j=1}^k a_{n+j}$ is bounded amd increasing.

Comment: Could you give more detaisl?

Comment: Bounded and increasing sequences converge. Say that $s_n$ converges to $s$. Then the series converges to $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n+s$.